# how to add key and UNIQUE KEY to existing table without check to speed up performance?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, foreign-key

i have very big InnoDB tables in MYSQL 5.6 version , i want to add KEY an UNIQUE KEY as fast as i can , the data is from restored database so all keys are checked , i am looking something like `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` in FOREIGN KEY . is there something like this for keys ?

Comment: A KEY is implemented via an index, you can't add a KEY without the index being created if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Adding an index _may_ speed up performance.  A `UNIQUE` key is both an index and a uniqueness check.  The uniqueness check does not speed up performance.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, what key you want to add, the size of the table, and the`SELECT` that you hope to speed up.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to achieve improved performance for the restore process of an SQL dump file. In that case, you can use do [`SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_unique_checks) before inserting the data and then `SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=1;` afterwards.

(`mysqldump` already does this automatically, at least for MariaDB.)

See also the [documentation for bulk loading data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html).

Comment: i have indexes matches yo my query i am interesting in dump and restore to different server my entire DB

Comment: @junior_software I've modified my answer now that I hopefully better understand what you're asking.